# Adapt Android to run apps in parallel

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

The idea is to port Android to a new soc for a given device class and run apps on this headless device. 
Multiple apps shall run stable at the same time. How can this be achieved with Android? So the difference is that not like on a smartphone there is only one foreground app at any time but multiple apps running in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Using a BroadcastReceiver handling the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` you can run code on background in applications that will start with the system boot. This way you will not even be worried about the UI part.

Assuming you know the package of your other applications, You can also start other applications running:

`Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(examplePackageName);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);`

If you have adb installed on the device you can also run from the shell:

```
"monkey -p <examplePackageName> -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1\n"
```

If you keep some kind of communication (e.g HTTP or socket based)(server-client) between the device and the phone, the app it will not be killed, I don't know if this solution feet on your architecture requirements :p

Comment: thx these are good hints. My main concern is that android is killing apps regularly. how to avoid this?

Comment: Yeah I was to write about that as well, I'm using <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/> this permission in an app I'm developing but it does not seem to completely solve the problem. You can also use AlarmManager with Wakelocks if you trully want prevent the Android from killing your app. Just search for that keywords ;)

Comment: someone told me also about different buckets like visible, foreground. And one can tweak the settings of the buckets to avoid killing. Do you know anything about that approach?

Comment: Yes, if you have a rooted phone you can simulate taps on the screen, I think is that you are asking for right ?

Comment: no the device is headless w/o screen, thus the apps shall run multiple in parallel